# ValueError when importing and using JSON string from file

Tags: python, json, file, dictionary

I have a dictionary like so:

```
{
    'cost' : cost,
    'oLen' : oLen
}
```

I write this to the file so the file contains:

```
{'oLen': 32, 'cost': 2048}
```

Later, I do this:

```
    with open('conf.conf') as f:
        config = json.loads(f.read())
    print config['oLen']
```

And get this:

```
ValueError: Expecting property name: line 1 column 2 (char 1)
```

If I change json.loads to json.dumps, I get:

```
TypeError: string indices must be integers, not str
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use double quotes in your JSON.

If you use `json.dump` to write the original dictionary to the file, you won't need to worry about it though!

```
>>> with open('output', 'w') as f:
    json.dump({'oLen': 32, 'cost': 2048}, f)

>>> with open('output') as f:
    obj = json.load(f)

>>> print(obj)
{'cost': 2048, 'oLen': 32}
```

Comment: I think you mean json.dumps, not dump

Comment: @Aurora you can use either, but `json.dumps` returns a string. `json.dump` writes straight to a file, which is what I'm doing here :)

Answer (score 1):

You need to use **Double** Quotations

```
{"oLen": 32, "cost": 2048}
```

[JSON example](http://json.org/example.html)